# Confusión entre Él me cae bien vs. Ella me cae bien

Tags: traducción, gramática

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/) (Spanish → English) is confusing me lately (either that, or *it's* confused):

*Google Translate (español → inglés) está confundiéndome recientemente (o eso sí está confundido):*

> Él me cae bien

translates to / *se traduce a*

> [I like him](https://translate.google.com/#es/en/%C3%89l%20me%20cae%20bien)

But, when I enter / *Pero, cuando introduzco*

> *Ella* me cae bien

this translates to / *ésto se traduce a*

> [She likes me](https://translate.google.com/#es/en/Ella%20me%20cae%20bien)

Notice the swapped subject and object. *Observe el sujeto y el objeto intercambiados.*

Which is grammatically correct? *¿Cual es correcta gramaticalmente?*

P.S. I do agree that the subject and object in the above statements are "transitive" (i.e. they are semantically equal no matter the order).  But, I'm more curious about the specific translation here.

*PD Sí, estoy de acuerdo en que el sujeto y el objeto en las frases anteriores son "transitivas" (es decir, son semánticamente iguales, no importa el orden). Pero, estoy más curioso sobre de la traducción específica aquí.*

Comment: Please roll back my edit if necessary.  I replaced "transliteration" with "translation."  Here's an example of what I understand for *transliteration*: When Germans transliterated Russian words they used their phonetic system.  Thus, in "Tchaikovsky," the V that we see there should actually be pronounced like our F.

Comment: @aparente001: thanks, my use of "transliteration" was (semantically) incorrect here.   Also, thanks for pointing out the subtle distinction between _gustar_ and _caer_ in your comment below.

Comment: Yes, that's a good lesson to learn early on to avoid misunderstandings or embarrassment.  I think most texts for learning Spanish don't make a clear point about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Translate is confused about the second sentence (why I don't know). If you've already grasped the somewhat convoluted grammar of the verb *gustar*, then you should have no problem grasping *caer bien*, because in this respect they work mostly in the same way.

Both these pairs mean essentially* the same thing:

- *Él me gusta.* / *Me gusta él.*
- *Él me cae bien.* / *Me cae bien él.*

The meaning is "I like him." Substitute *ella* for *él* and the meaning changes, of course, to "I like her."

***Note well**: *gustar* (when the subject is a person) has a sexual connotation that *caer bien* lacks. So *caer bien* is actually safer for a non-native speaker unsure of the context.

Now about the grammar: formally, in *Ella me cae bien*, the subject is *ella* and *me* is the indirect object. They function as in the phrase *Ella me dio un beso* ("She gave me a kiss"). You can't analyze such things by examining the English translation (much less a Google translation).

If you wanted to swap the actors, it would have to be *Yo le caigo bien a ella* ("She likes me"). You can omit *a ella*, but *le* has no gender so you have to rely on context if there's both an *ella* and an *él* nearby.

*Caer* in this usage means "affect", "induce a certain state of mind", "produce a given sensation". *Caer* of course means "to fall", or sometimes "to land". Imagine something or someone falls on you, or lands on you, figuratively. It may land right and softly, or it may fall on you like a ton of bricks. That's the idea behind *caer bien* and its antonym *caer mal* (also *caer fatal* and others).

Comment: Great grammatical explanation and nice development of intuition about *caer*.  Let's make sure the OP knows that *caer* is a great way to prevent misunderstandings that can occur with *gustar* (which might be assumed to have a sexual connotation).  I wouldn't have mentioned this except that your answer might lead someone to think that the two verbs are interchangeable.

Comment: @aparente001 That's a very pertinent observation. I'm adding it to my answer now.

Comment: @pablodf76 (and aparente001): thank you for the answer and comments.  I consider myself fluent with _gustar_ and _caer_ (in this context), but while I might like her, she might _not_ like me.  Thus, my original question bears some importance here. :-)

Comment: @pablodf76: also, your comment regarding the metaphorical usage of _caer_ reminds me of _llevar bien_ (as in "_Nos llevamos bien_") -- perhaps somewhat related?

Comment: @pr1268 Yes. Actually *nos caemos bien* ~ *nos llevamos bien*.